# On a mobile device, can I extract data from html using a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

My app parses PC html pages and renders them based on native UI components. Currently I'm working on Android, and use Jsoup to extract data from html.

But now I wish to port my app to iOS, WindowsPhone and other platforms.

So I came to this idea, parsing html with the specified platform's WebView. I googled the use case but find nothing.

I wanna try to implement it as below,

1. download html, load it into a WebView.
2. inject zepto.js and my own parse.js into the WebView to traverse DOM and find the data I need.
3. pass the parsed data to native method to render the native view.

The key issue is how can I prevent WebView to render the raw html to improve performance. I wish WebView to parse DOM and run javascript silently, ignore all CSS, do not paint at all (GUI-Less).

How can I achieve this?

Or is it worthy to parse html using WebView instead of Jsoup?

Comment: did you try to use javascriptinterface for this. and also set javaScriptEnable=true to your webview object..

Comment: yes technically it works. But I wish it would run as a server mode, GUI-less, like node-dom (Node.js) or HtmlUnit (Java). If GUI-less is impossilbe, is there any method to reduce CPU/memory comsuption of WebView rendering as much as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to prevent a `WebView` from rendering `Html`. A `WebView` is a View, it has no GUI-less mode.

To ignore `css` just don't provide a base url, then it won't find the `css` files (inline will still be there though).

For what you want to do a `WebView` is not the correct tool.